# Guzzle Post Null/Empty Values in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, guzzle

I've been trying to work with Guzzle and learn my way around it, but I'm a bit confused about using a request in conjunction with empty or null values.

For example:

```php
$response = $client->request('POST', 
    'https://www.testsite.com/coep/public/api/donations', [
    'form_params' => [
        'client' => [
            'web_id' => NULL,
            'name' => 'Test Name',
            'address1' => '123 E 45th Avenue',
            'address2' => 'Ste. 1',
            'city' => 'Nowhere',
            'state' => 'CO',
            'zip' => '80002'
        ],
        'contact' => [],
        'donation' => [
            'status_id' => 1,
            'amount' => $donation->amount,
            'balance' => $donation->balance,
            'date' => $donation->date,
            'group_id' => $group->id,
        ],
    ]
]);
```

After running a test, I found out that `'web_id'` completely disappears from my request if set to NULL. My question is how do I ensure that it is kept around on the request to work with my conditionals?

At this point, if I dd the `$request->client`, all I get back is everything but the `web_id`. Thanks!

Comment: Use an empty string: `'web_id' => '',`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I ran into this issue yesterday and your question is very well ranked on Google. Shame that it has no answer.

The problem here is that `form_params` uses [http_build_query()](http://docs.php.net/manual/da/function.http-build-query.php) under the hood and as stated in [this user contributed note](http://docs.php.net/manual/da/function.http-build-query.php#60523), null params are not present in the function's output.

I suggest that you pass this information via a JSON body (by using `json` as key instead of `form_params`) or via multipart (by using `multipart` instead of `form_params`).

Note: those 2 keys are available as constants, respectively `GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions::JSON` and `GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions::MULTIPART`

Comment: Thanks bro, solved by using json instead of form_params

Answer (score 0):

Try to define anything like `form_params`, `headers` or `base_uri` before creating a client, so:

```
// set options, data, params BEFORE...

$settings = [
    'base_uri' => 'api.test',
    'headers' => [
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
        'Authorization' => 'ajustneedatokenheredontworry'                
    ],
    'form_params' => [
        'cash' => $request->cash,
        'reason' => 'I have a good soul'
    ]
];


// ...THEN create your client,

$client = new GuzzleClient($settings);


// ...and finally check your response.

$response = $client->request('POST', 'donations');
```

If you check `$request->all()` at the controller function that you are calling, you should see that were sent successfully.

Answer (score 0):

For those using laravel, use this:

```
Http::asJson()
```